# Communicating with a USB driver

Tags: java, c, driver

I have a MIDI to USB cable which installed a USB driver on my computer. The driver appears under the sound drivers category.

How is it possible to communicate with the driver and get all the available functions? Is there certain libraries for this?

PS: this is a stackoverflow question because I want to develop a program that will communicate with that driver!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're programming in C you could probably just use this API to communicate with your MIDI device: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712058.aspx

edit: after spending a few seconds on Google (did you tried that at all??): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/midi/package-summary.html

Comment: But I am not providing a midi input, because I am plugging a usb into the PC. Isn't the MIDI signal transfered into a USB signal through the cable?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking in the last comment, but it shouldn't matter how it's connected: either USB or PCI or whatever technology. The driver shipped with your USB to MIDI cable should make the device available through that API. The fact that it shows up as a MIDI device under sound cards in the device manager confirms it does so.

Answer (score 0):

[Java RXTX Library](http://rxtx.qbang.org/) communicates with USB Driver